# Finding marginal density function with bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to find the marginal density functions of $X$ and $Y$ from the joint probability density
$$
f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
xy &, \quad 0<x<2,0<y<2,x+y<2\\
0 &, \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

While I understand $f_X(x)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x,y)dy$ and likewise for $f_Y(y)$, I'm not exactly sure what $x+y<2$ tells us. Does this affect the bounds of integration at all?

Comment: It does effect the region at which you integrate over to get unity - so you will have a triangle which you need to integrate over. $$\int_0^2dy\int_0^{2-y}dx (..)$$

Comment: ... which suggests to me that the joint pdf integrates to $\frac23$ and needs to be adjusted

Answer (score 1):

[image: Integral bounds]

It always helps to graph it out.

$f_Y(y)=\displaystyle\int_0^{2-y}xydx$

And

$f_X(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{2-x}xydy$